# Parallel Process Functions in PyQT Will Not Return

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing

PyQT novice here. Building a GUI for my program, and the parts involving multiprocessing are where I am stuck.

Essentially, these functions will not return and go back to the GUI once they finish. The program becomes stuck inside of whatever the function is that is called if it is multiprocessing.

Here is the excerpt of the code in the MainWindow class which calls the functions that perform multiprocessing (map in particular)

```
def parallel_process_from_gui(self):
    self.log.info('Running parallel processing')
    parallelResults = template_time_parallel_process(self.inputDF1,self.newFile.inputDict, self.targetPath, self.inputDF2, self.threshold)
    self.log.info('Finished parallel processing')
```

Below lies the code which is being called and will not return (i.e. program will reach 'Returning from parallel_process' but will not log 'Finished parallel processing' from above).

```
def parallel_process(inputDF1,inputDict,targetPath,inputDF2,threshold):
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    try:
        numCores = 80
        p = mp.Pool(numCores)
        parallelProcessArgs = ([inputDict,targetPath,val,threshold,inputDF2] for val in inputDF1)

        p.map(some_parallel_function,parallelProcessArgs)

        parallelProcessArgs2 = ([inputDict,val,targetPath,threshold] for val in inputDF1) #Packages all of the arguments up for parallel processing

        results = p.map(some_parallel_function2,parallelProcessArgs2)
        resultsFlattened = [val for sublist in results for val in sublist] #Flattens the list of lists

        p.close()

    except Exception:
        log.error(traceback.format_exc())

    log.info('returning from parallel_process')
    return resultsFlattened
```

The parallel processing functions themselves work, as they were adopted from the previous program and just made to be called from my GUI (learned the hard way I can't seem to multiprocess directly in the GUI code or I get a new GUI instantiated for every process...whoops). I think I am just making a novice mistake with PyQT.

I have attempted to run parallel_process from the same app.py file, as well as putting in a separate .py file altogether and call from there (such as main.py), but with no luck fixing the issue.

Comment: 1. Are these two functions `template_time_parallel_process` and `parallel_process` the same functions? Did you unintentionally changed their names? Or are they two different functions on your code? 2. Can your application print things on console (stdout/stderr)? If no, that's why you use log.info and log.error? 3. Can you ensure that the variable `resultsFlattened` exists after `log.info('returning from parallel_process')` line, and guarantee that the function _does return_? From the description on the post, the function is not returning, and the error is not being catched. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hey Carl, 1.template_time_parallel_process and parallel_process are the same function, simply mis-copied something.   2. I can print things to console but am working with creating log files.    3. I have verified resultsFlattened exists.  My other function that utilizes p.map() works as well, but just leaves the program in a frozen state as well instead of returning.... Do I need to be connecting signals or states perhaps?

Comment: As long as you keep using the python multiprocessing module instead of the QProcess class, or anything qt compatible, signals and slots won't help you to unstuck the app. My guess was that there was some crash that was not being catched by the app, and not showing on the console. But, now you say that the app freezes? Based on the _example you posted_ (not your source code), it makes no sense to me that the app freezes right after it logs 'returning from parallel_process'... I'd expect it to freeze the app whenever you'd call p.map, as that is the only blocking function on the post afaik.

Comment: I'd suggest you to attempt to create a minimal reproducible example of your problem, and insert it on the post, so we can also run it ourselves. My guess is that, something is indeed wrong with the code, but you are probably having trouble to explain/grasp what is it. That's all I can comment about it for now.